# Need Memory impact on "Five Activities" Vs "Five Fragments in Activity"

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-activity, memory-management

**Description :**
* Actually I have, five activity's in my project. I want to choose the best memory optimized one. 
* I don't have any multi-device support constraint.
* I **need better explanation** on, which of the below is best in terms of memory optimization.

1) Creating Five Activities.

2) Five Fragments in Activity.

I don't have any constraints in choosing any of above options based on memory optimization, without .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far as memory management the approach here doesn't really make a difference. The OS intelligently uses memory and saves and restores as needed for both Activities and Fragments. Really what would determine which to use is based more on how the application works and you choose to design it.

Having a single Activity manage a set of Fragments generally makes sense if all the Fragments are interrelated. So for instance if your app has three tabs you would probably have one Activity manage three Fragments that are swapped out when the tabs change. Although it is also possible to design an entire application with one Activity that swaps out all its fragments. Your question is far too broad to be answered.